# How to fill ContextMenuStrip in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, winforms-interop

I've created WPF application with `NotifyIcon` to work in tray.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public NotifyIcon NotifyIcon { get; } = new NotifyIcon
    {
        Icon = Properties.Resources.status_on_ico,
        Visible = true
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = MyContextMenuStrip;
        NotifyIcon.Click += NotifyIcon_Click;
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void NotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

XAML of main window is nothing special and not relevant.

I want to create `ContextMenuStrip` of `NotifyIcon` in XAML (I know how to do it code behind but don't want it).

Here is what I've managed.

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:ContextMenuStrip x:Name="MyContextMenuStrip" TopLevel="False">
        <wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
            <!-- How to add items here? -->
        </wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
    </wf:ContextMenuStrip>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

The question is how to add items to `ContextMenuStrip.Items` with `Name` and `Click` event handlers in XAML?

Comment: Have you considered using [hardcodet's native MotifyIcon library for WPF](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon/comment-page-3)?  No winforms interop needed, unless you are using it for other things.

Comment: Yes, but not sure if it is robust enough to use it in enterprise app. To be honest I'm not WPF purist and some embedded Windows Forms controls 
in my apps don't confuse me.

Comment: If the answer to my question is "It's impossible" I'll stick with code behind solution (which is trivial). `NotifyIcon` is very little piece of code in my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is how to add items to ContextMenuStrip.Items with Name and Click event handlers in XAML?

Try this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:ContextMenuStrip x:Name="MyContextMenuStrip" TopLevel="False">
        <wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
            <wf:ToolStripMenuItem Text="test1" Click="It_Click" />
            <wf:ToolStripMenuItem Text="test2" />
        </wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
    </wf:ContextMenuStrip>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

---

```
private void It_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("click!");
}
```